# OpenShift fails to deploy jenkins - connection refused

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I am using the GitHub project [elio/openshift-vagrant](https://github.com/eliu/openshift-vagrant). vagrant up and then the script oc-up.sh gives me a master and two nodes. Ansible provision runs without problems.

After provision I can login to https://master.example.com:8443 as admin. I can create a project. When I try to deploy *jenkins-ephemeral* this fails with message

> error: couldn't get deployment jenkins-1: Get
>   https://172.30.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/test2/replicationcontrollers/jenkins-1:  dial tcp 172.30.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

Ansible installer status shows no problems in the cluster. Why is this not working? How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set Jenkins ssh key to have access to source?
Another point is to validate if the SSH port is open. According to error can be one of these things